# Homestead: command not found- Windows 10 - Tried everything

Tags: php, bash, command, homestead

Receiving bash Homestead command not found

```
//After running    composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"
```

Changed current directory to `C:/Users/Eric/AppData/Roaming/Composer`
`./composer.json` has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files

```
//Inside my vi ~/.zshrc

export PATH=/Users/eric/AppData/Roaming/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH
export PATH="$laravel:$PATH"
```

I enabled Virtualization in BIOS

//  Inside etc/hosts

Hosts:

`127.0.0.1`       homestead.app

`192.168.10.10`     homestead.app

//Inside environmental variables

`C:\Users\Eric\AppData\Roaming\composer\vendor\bin`

I can't find the homestead.yaml folder and I can't run any homestead commands. Any help with this would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Can you be more specific? Apparently you have Windows OS. DO you have VirtualBox and Vagrant installed? Did you create Homestead virtual machine?

Comment: @Mirceac21 yeah, I am using VirtualBox and Vagrant, and I believe I am using the latest lavarel/homestead virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already have `VirtualBox, Vagrant, Git Bash (Git for Windows)` installed and working you have two options to install `Homestead`

1. Using `Git Bash`:

Open git bash, navigate to home directory (typically it's `C:\Users\{username}`) and run

`git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead`.

This will download Homestead in `C:\Users\{username}\Homestead` directory.

Then go to the Homestead installation directory

`cd ~/Homestead` and run `bash init.sh`.

This last command will create the Homestead configuration file (`homestead.yaml`).

2. Using `composer`

You need to have PHP and Composer already installed.

Open `git bash` and run `composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"` command.

To take advantage of the Homestead CLI, make sure to add the Composer /bin directory to your PATH e.g. command prompt with admin privileges:
`set PATH=%PATH%;%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin`

Then to create the Homestead configuration file (`homestead.yaml`) you have to run `homestead init`.

If none of the above don't work you can use Laragon http://laragon.org/.

Comment: After completing up to bash init.sh I receive a homestead is initialized!, however I am still unable to run the homestead commands. When trying to run ~/composer/vendor/bin/homestead directly, I receive this error                                                                                                    PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'C:\Users\Eric\composer\vendor/composer/autoload_real.php' (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\Users\Eric\composer\vendor\autoload.php on line 5                      thanks again, I may just use laragon